# Elasticsearch error: Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch, dockerfile, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to create a Docker image with Elasticsearch installed. I know that Elasticsearch already has his custom Docker image but I need to use the same environment of the AWS Lambda Function with Python 3.6.5 installed. So I had to extend the AWS Docker image and I had to install the Elasticsearch service.

Here you can find my Dockerfile:

```
FROM lambci/lambda-base:build

ENV PATH=/var/lang/bin:$PATH \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lang/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH \
    AWS_EXECUTION_ENV=AWS_Lambda_python3.6 \
    PYTHONPATH=/var/runtime \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/var/lang/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig

RUN rm -rf /var/runtime /var/lang && \
  curl https://lambci.s3.amazonaws.com/fs/python3.6.tgz | tar -xz -C / && \
  sed -i '/^prefix=/c\prefix=/var/lang' /var/lang/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.6.pc && \
  curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/Python-3.6.8.tar.xz | tar -xJ && \
  cd Python-3.6.8 && \
  LIBS="$LIBS -lutil -lrt" ./configure --prefix=/var/lang && \
  make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) libinstall libainstall inclinstall && \
  cd .. && \
  rm -rf Python-3.6.8

EXPOSE 9200 9300

# Add these as a separate layer as they get updated frequently
RUN pip install -U pip setuptools --no-cache-dir && \
    pip install -U virtualenv pipenv --no-cache-dir && \
    pip install -U awscli boto3 aws-sam-cli==0.10.0 aws-lambda-builders==0.1.0 --no-cache-dir && \
    yum install wget -y && \
    echo "vm.max_map_count=262144" >> /etc/sysctl.conf && \
    # I try to install elasticsearch manually
    wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-6.6.1.rpm && \
    rpm --install elasticsearch-6.6.1.rpm && \
    service elasticsearch start && \
    chkconfig --add elasticsearch && \
    sed -i -e "s/#network.host: 192.168.0.1/network.host: 127.0.0.1/g" /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml && \
    sed -i -e "s/#http.port: 9200/http.port: 9200/g" /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml && \
    sed -i -e "s/# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory./network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1\nnetwork.publish_host: localhost/g" /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

RUN service elasticsearch start && \
    service elasticsearch status && \
    service elasticsearch status
```

When I build the image, the image is built correctly and the elasticsearch service is running. I can see the log: `elasticsearch (pid  87) is running...`. The problem is that I can't make API call to http://localhost:9200 because it says: `Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

I need to use the elasticsearch service inside the container and not from outside. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't start background services in a Dockerfile (they don't get persisted in the image).  Typical uses of `service` in Docker don't work for a couple of reasons, and you should launch the service directly.  (Try another `RUN service elasticsearch status` command and see what it says.)

Comment: Also the `bind_host: 127.0.0.1` setting is a guarantee that the service will be unreachable from outside the container.  You usually want 0.0.0.0 in Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze you're right. If I run another `RUN service elasticsearch status` command, I get `elasticsearch dead but pid file exists`. How can I launch the service directly?
I don't need to use the service outside the container but I need to use the elasticsearch service inside the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've also added the command `CMD elasticsearch start && bash` at the end of the Dockerfile but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate how you are actually running the docker container. Simply exposing the port in the docker file isn't enough. You have to run with the `-p` option as well. For example:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 <image name here>
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ for details.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't decide how to run the docker container because I'm using this image in AWS CodeBuild.
In this service you can only select the image to be used and then it runs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use the internal ip address of your app. This is how you get it

```
dokku elasticsearch:info <Your elasticsearch container name here>
```

Then you can now do

```
curl http://172.75.0.7:9200
```

Assuming your internal IP is 172.75.0.7

Comment: Yes, I want to use the internal IP address of my app. I discovered that it's a problem of AWS CodeBuild. In this service, you can't use the `localhost` word and the internal IP because there's a network restriction. (it's the answer from an AWS Solution Architect).
The only thing that I had to do was to create a new Docker container with the Elasticsearch service installed and expose the port. Now I'm able to make API calls from my Docker container to the Elasticsearch Docker